# cURL API Extremely Slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, api, curl

I have created many websites that get all there data from a API.
(located on the same server on most cases).

The websites are operation really slow, of all the curl requests.

I first thought it was our mysql server (sepparate server) but now we implemented caching it's still slow.

Is there a good way to find out why it takes so long to do the curl requests.
And what would be a good way to go?

Comment: Is is it slow if you copy and paste the URL into your browser?

Comment: I could be several things. Start with loggin in to your server and checking how fast you can load websites with wget. If this also takes long, it may be something with your nameservers and/or hosts file

Comment: no not really, but in my browser i just do one request, a website can do like 50.

wget is slow aswell. I think it could be the nameserver, but how do i find out?

Comment: If you could call the api from the browser you could check the network tab to see how long it took for the dns lookup. Alternatively you could use nslookup command to see how long resolving takes.

Comment: nslookup goes really fast. Could it have something todo with the webserver itself, i'm using Plesk with nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a browser rest client to point to your API and use a profiling tool (xdebug/xhprof) to find the source of the bottleneck. 
Possibly make sure the api calls resolve locally and dont go all the way out to the internet before coming back in (but may not shave off much time).
Would recommend starting with the APIs code.

Comment: I just did this. The loading time for one request changes between 150ms to 1500 ms in some rear cases. (same url).

Comment: On the slow requests do you have any idea on the dns lookup time and api response (code dealing with request) time?

Comment: No not a clue. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: If using the browser you can use network tab (see above). Curl will not give you much useful data on where the problem is. Can I ask how you gathered the data you have on response time? Is it something calling the api locally (without requiring a dns request)?

Comment: The curl is just asking the public url, so I think then its going over the internet and not poll localy. My browsers tells me it takes 238ms to do the first request. (before recieving first byte).

Could it have somehting todo with gzip or something like that?

Comment: Seems important here to be able to run benchmarks on your api locally I.e. a script (sitting on same server as api) hitting it 50 times a second ect. That way you may be able to determine if it is a code issue. You could use A tool like apache bench (ab) or run php scripts to do it for you.

Comment: Doesn't sound like gzip is the issue. 200ms is not much (theres a million in a second). If anything gzip will be helping performance. Try benchmarking locally and then using same technique but over the internet and gather some data. You may still need to profile the api code base to look for the bottlenecks.

Comment: I created a script in php running on the same server for this case. Hitting the API with 250 requests after each other. 150 times with file_get_c. and with cURL. FGC: 23 seconds, CURL 20 seconds to load.

Comment: Maybe run the same script externally and then compare times with those run on same server. If there's minimal difference then you have to look to the code and run some profiling.

Comment: Just did that, other server, other hoster: (2 diffrent) the first one takes 41 seconds on the curl, second server was even slower... then I would say it should be in the API?

Comment: So if you are saying it is taking over double time to do it externally, I am not sure if that is the API then (not sure if I have understood correctly). But could still be worth profiling the API code base as fixing network latency could be harder (unless there's something obvious causing the latency) inside the Internet jungle.

Comment: You're right, it takes double the time to run in from a server not at the same host location. (our other server polling the API on the first server is also at a 23 seconds time). Tomorrow I will test more with a json file, instead of our API, to check the loading times. (thanks for the help so far!)

Comment: Hmm interesting so might well be a dns setting or network configuration. No worries, don't forget to mark the ticket as answered when you are done.

Comment: Loading the same data from a json file it takes 0.2 seconds for 150 calls. So much faster.. so then I should have a problem in my API?

Comment: Yes suggests network latency is minimal and code base is the problem, suggest getting yourself aquatinted with profiling tools such as xdebug. I'm off to bed for now, good luck

Comment: if theres anything else requiring an answer please ask (or possibly start a new question on here or email me), if you are happy with the answer please set it as accepted, thanks.

Comment: I think I found a few problems. When I try to load a single php file with the content it takes about one second to do that 350 times. When i add all my classes as includes, it goes up to around the 4 seconds. But when I setup my db connection and ask the data from the database it goes up to around 26 seconds. There is the main problem I guess. Is there a way to find out why the loading times are that long? The DB is not on the same server.

Comment: The slow query logs are emtpy, (as nothing within this DB is showing up)

Comment: grab the executed sql statement and run an explain on it, possibly might need sql query cache or adding some indexes. sounds like the database is he bottleneck though. mind you 350 times is alot and really depends on how heavy the queries are....profile the queries with explain. might be an idea to start a new question for this now

Comment: I just did that, used the function from the class to get the results. If I run the function on my single page php. It duration goes up to 7 seconds. The exact same statement running from my class function takes 27 seconds. How is that possible?! SO then I would say its not my DB, 6/7 seconds for 350 large querys is not bad.

Comment: not sure i fully understand what you are referring to. run the sql in question on the db itself and check how long that takes, use explain so you can review where it might be slowing it down

Comment: I did that. 1 SIMPLE ccdn_cmdt ref un_ccdnnid_cmdttid,fk_ccdncmdt_ccdn_nid,fk_ccdncmd... fk_ccdncmdt_cmdt_tid 4 const 36754 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
1 SIMPLE ccd_note eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 olon_1375.ccdn_cmdt.ccdn_nid 1. The query is extremly fast by my judgement. Could it be a slow connection between the two servers?

Comment: could check the network latency between the 2 points by using one of tools mentons here http://serverfault.com/questions/5111/how-to-test-real-network-throughput-between-two-points

Comment: When I just only the pdo execute statement it drops back to 8 seconds. When putting in the fecthAll() it takes 28 seconds. So there should be the problem...

Comment: So i used iperf to do a network test. THe results are schocking good. Bandwidth is 87.9 Mbits/sec. That doenst look to be the problem?

Comment: ok so its not network latency between web and api and not between api and db. As i understand it when using the pdo statment its 8 secs and with fetchAll its 28 secs...perhaps stick with pdo statement if thats the case

Comment: I need the fetchAll to get the content out. But maybe opening a new question is better, it's a nother problem! Thank you for all the thinking ;)

Comment: @TimHanssen if this is the correct answer for the post please mark as answered. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the cURL request.